# If I play C1, F1, G1 - will F1 and G1 together cause dissonance or sound bad(to most people)?

Tags: chords, harmony, chord-theory

If i play C1, F1, G1 at the same time:

• C1 & F1 = Perfect 4th
• C1 & G1 = Perfect 5th

● What about F1 & G1 at the same time?

- Would these sound bad together?  (to most people)
- What is their relationship?

Comment: What did you think when you tried it? On what instrument/s?

Comment: Do you really mean octave 1? That's the lowest. If these were played in octave 4 or 5 the sound will be very different.

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking C-F-G is known as a "sus4" chord. Historically it would be considered dissonant, but in modern music, especially jazz and rock/pop it's a very standard chord that would not bother the typical listener. In fact, it often has a very pleasing effect.

Playing F and G together, out of context, would most likely be perceived as dissonant.

The relationship between F and G is a "major second". As with the sus4 chord, the interval itself is dissonant by historical definition, but is frequent in more modern music and is not heard as harsh.

There is a caveat to all this. Playing C1-F1-G1 would sound "muddy", at best, on many instruments. When notes that are relatively close together are played simultaneously in a low register, they tend to clash a great deal. However, C4-F4-G4, for example, would have a better sound.

---

The "to most people" part of the question is unanswerable. What sounds good or bad is influenced by too many factors -- cultural background and exposure to music, especially.